# Exception handling not working for PG npm package

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I installed `"pg": "^8.0.2"` and created the `database.js` file with database credentials. But no matter what go wrong it never enters in the `catch block` to show error. Instead it always logs `connected to the database`. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong. Thank You!

**Database.js**

```
const Pool = require('pg').Pool;

  const pool = new Pool({
    user: 'roothjk',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'sf',
    password: 'admin',
    port: 5432
  });
  try {
    pool.connect()
    console.log('connected to the db');

  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Error connecting to db');

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`connect` returns a `Promise`, and then you move to the next statement. Instead, you should use the `then` and `cath` **methods**:

```
pool.connect()
    .then(c => console.log('connected to the db'))
    .catch(e => console.log('Error connecting to db'));
```